# How efficient is writing to an HDFS file in several steps?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I know that an HDFS block size is 64 MB. But let us say I create a new HDFS file, and keep on writing data to it, but at one time write data as little as say just 4KB. Would that be very inefficient? By the end my file could be 1GB in size, but does writting data little by little make writing to such a file inefficient? I mean, is it important to buffer my data before writing to the file. In this case for example, I could keep accumulating data into a buffer, until it reaches a size of 64 MB, and then write it to the HDFS file, and repeat that procedure after clearing that buffer.

Comment: Which method are you using to write the file?

Comment: Yes, use a buffer (or whatever) to write out in "chunks".

Comment: I am using the apache's library for writing to the HDFS.

Comment: Interesting to me..., which library you are using for checking buffer memory in mb before writing to hdfs. and what file type (avro,orc, or something else)? If thats the case I think thats the correct way to do it. I have seen people merging the small files till it reaches approximate block size(they called it as standardization) but in your case if its success then thats correct!

Answer (score 0):

First of all HDFS blocksize is up to you, the default is configurable, and you can set a different blocksize for a given file when you put it to HDFS.

If your data is not at hand when you want to place it to HDFS, then use Flume, set up the source to your data generator, and your sink to a file on HDFS, and let the tool do its job without struggling with the details. If the data is in a database, you can turn to Sqoop also.

Otherwise if you are experimenting, then do performance tests, and check which approach is better, it depends heavily on how your data is generated and how you use which library.

Comment: @pitfa: I think he is not asking about data ingestion. suggested flume or sqoop approach may be correct.